# Erro ao exibir video html

Tags: html, html5, codeigniter

Estou colocando um vídeo usando html5 e codeigniter em minha página, mas está exibindo apenas o player sem exibir o video.

### script:

```
<video width="420" height="340" autoplay controls>
  <source src="<?php echo base_url('assets/videos/teste.mp4'); ?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <p>Desculpe o transtorno, mas seu navegador não pode exibir o vídeo.</p>    
</video>
```

Criei também um .htaccess com o seguinte conteúdo na pasta onde está o vídeo com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já citado nas respostas o mais provável é que a extensão do arquivo não esta sendo interpretada pelo navegador("Verifique o caminho do arquivo também").
acredito que isso resolva o seu problema.

```
<video width="420" height="340" autoplay controls>
     <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
     <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
     <!--(X)HTML Caso queira uma solução em flash -->
     <p>Navegador não suporta o elemento video da HTML5.<br>Faça <a href="video.mp4">download do video</a></p>

</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solução

```
<source src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/videos/teste.mp4'); ?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
```

uma barra antes do **assets** no caminho do vídeo

Comment: Resposta acima @Away

Comment: Não resolveu... o problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Away,

pode ser o tipo de video que esta tentando executar com o navegador que não reconhece.

Como por exemplo o chrome da a certeza que irá exibir videos com o formato `.ogg`, já o `Mozzila` e o `IE` não.

Um fomato que é bem comum que alguns navegadores aceitam, dependendo da versão do mesmo, é o formato `.mp4`, como você mesmo utilizou.

Você pode tentar colocando um tipo de extensão para cada navegador e verificar se funciona, retire tambem o `type` e o `codecs`.

Como disse anteriormente, dependendo da versão do navegador pode não reconhecer o formato `.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei, mas fiz um teste e funcionou normal aqui.

Só para teste mesmo, tenta acessar sem o base_url, tenta direto

[**Olha um teste do JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnZEZ/)